# how to insert records after clicking command button?

Tags: apex, visualforce, commandbutton

I want to insert records after clicking the create button.In my code the record are inserted.but i want to insert record after clicking "create" button

```
public class ItemController {

    public book__c book {
        get;
        set;
    }

    public ItemController() {
        book = new book__c();
    }

    public PageReference insertNewItem() {

        insert book;
        //reset public property for new insert
        book = new book__c();

        return null;
    }
}
```

Visualforce page:

```
<apex:page controller="ItemController">
    <apex:form>
        <apex:pageBlock>
            <apex:pageBlockSection>
                <apex:inputField value="{!book.Name}" />
                <apex:inputField value="{!book.amount__c}" />
                <apex:inputField value="{!book.color__c}" />
            </apex:pageBlockSection>
            <apex:pageBlockButtons>
                <apex:commandButton action="{!insertNewItem}" value="save" />
            </apex:pageBlockButtons>
        </apex:pageBlock>
    </apex:form>
</apex:page>
```

Comment: Where is your **create** button? If it exists, just set the `action="{!insertNewItem}"` for that as you have done for the **save** button

Comment: Or just change the value="Save" to value="Create". Whoa! You now have a create button!

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest you to rather change the value of save button to the create as ur code is working correct as per ur requirement so the functionality of the code remains same.
Thanks